# Confirming Navigation with React Router without Mixin for es6 Classes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

With React Router is there a way to use confirm leaving a route without using a mixin? We are using es6 Classes and can't use a mixin.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:
https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/advanced/ConfirmingNavigation.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `History` module and then make use of `listenBefore()`:

```js
history.listenBefore(function (location) {
  if (input.value !== '') {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'
  }
})
```

Check the [Confirming Navigation](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/ConfirmingNavigation.md) docs.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the listenBefore and clear this out?

Comment: To remove the listener, you simply need to save what is returned and execute it. ```this.unlisten = browserHistory.listenBefore(function() {
  if (!window.confirm('Leaving?')) {
    return false;
  }
});

this.unlisten();```